# Remaining time for laptop battery in system tray with xfce4-power-manager?

Tags: laptop, xubuntu, battery, xfce4-power-manager

I'm using xubuntu on my laptop, and I wonder if there's a way to have the remaining time of my battery displayed in the system tray with the xfce power manager? It tells me how much time I got left when I mouseover the icon, but I could't for the life of me find an option to have it display that information in the system tray.

If that's not possible, I'd be happy about alternatives that could do what I'm looking for. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a 10.04 system which I still have in use, there is the xfce4-battery-plugin which does what you want.

In the web, the most recent release is 1.0.5 from 2012/05/30